# Hypixel Skyblock API not pulling all data from auction (Python)

Tags: python, minecraft, hypixel-api

For some reason my code fails to pull a bunch of random items from the auction house. I attached an image of how my [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRaYj.png) looks. I understand that Hypixel api isn't used by many and I doubt many that will see this plays minecraft, but if anyone has a solution to this that would be great!

This is my enchantments.py:

```
enchantments_list = ["placeholder"]
```

This is my API_KEY.json (you can get the api key by logging onto Hypixel and doing /api new in chat):

```
{"api_key":"key"}
```

And this is the Main.py:

```
import json
import os
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
from enchantments import enchantments_list
from colorama import Fore, Style

# Get the path to the API_KEY.json file in the same directory as the script
api_key_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'API_KEY.json')

# Load API key from JSON file
with open(api_key_path, 'r') as file:
    api_key = json.load(file)['api_key']

# API endpoint for auction house data
url = f"https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?key={api_key}"

# Send GET request to the API
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()

    # Check if the request was successful
    if data['success']:
        total_pages = data['totalPages']
        item_info = {}

        auction_count = 0
        bin_count = 0

        # Create a progress bar
        progress_bar = tqdm(total=total_pages, desc='Fetching Auction Data', unit='page')

        # Initialize variables to track failed items
        failed_items = []

        # Iterate through each page of auction data
        for page in range(1, total_pages + 1):
            # Send GET request for each page
            page_url = f"{url}&page={page}"
            page_response = requests.get(page_url)

            # Check if the request was successful
            if page_response.status_code == 200:
                page_data = page_response.json()

                # Check if the page contains auctions
                if 'auctions' in page_data:
                    # Iterate through each auction on the page
                    for auction in page_data['auctions']:
                        if auction['bin']:
                            bin_count += 1
                        else:
                            auction_count += 1

                        item_uuid = auction['uuid']
                        item_name = auction['item_name']
                        price = auction['starting_bid']
                        seller_uuid = auction['auctioneer']
                        enchantments = auction['item_lore'] if 'item_lore' in auction else 'None'

                        if item_name not in item_info:
                            item_info[item_name] = []

                        item_info[item_name].append((item_uuid, price, seller_uuid, enchantments))

                else:
                    print(f"No auctions found on page {page}")

            else:
                failed_items.extend(page_data.get('auctions', []))
                continue

            # Update the progress bar
            progress_bar.update()

        # Close the progress bar
        progress_bar.close()

        total_count = auction_count + bin_count

        # Sort items by quantity and price
        sorted_items = sorted(item_info.items(), key=lambda x: (sum([1 for _, _, _, _ in x[1]]), x[0]), reverse=True)

        # Save item names, prices, seller UUIDs, and enchantments in a text file
        output_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'item_info.txt')
        with open(output_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
            for item_name, info in sorted_items:
                output_file.write(f"{item_name}\n")

                # Sort the prices by descending order
                sorted_info = sorted(info, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

                for item_uuid, price, seller_uuid, enchantments in sorted_info:
                    # Filter items based on enchantments list
                    filtered_enchantments = [enchant for enchant in enchantments_list if enchant in enchantments]

                    # Check if the item contains any of the specified enchantments
                    if filtered_enchantments:
                        output_file.write(f"Price: {price} | Seller UUID: {seller_uuid} | Item UUID: {item_uuid} | Enchantments: {', '.join(filtered_enchantments)}\n")

                output_file.write("\n")

        # Format the page ranges
        page_ranges = []
        prev_page = 0
        for item in failed_items:
            page = item.get('page', 0)
            if not page_ranges or page != prev_page + 1:
                page_ranges.append([page])
            else:
                page_ranges[-1].append(page)
            prev_page = page

        page_range_str = ', '.join([f"{pages[0]}-{pages[-1]}" if len(pages) > 1 else str(pages[0]) for pages in page_ranges])

        print(f"Auction Count: {auction_count}")
        print(f"BIN Count: {bin_count}")
        print(f"Total Count: {total_count}")
        if failed_items:
            print(f"{Fore.RED}Failed to retrieve data for item(s):")
            for item in failed_items:
                print(f"Item UUID: {item['uuid']} | Item Name: {item['item_name']}")
            print(Style.RESET_ALL)
        #print(f"Data retrieved from page(s): {page_range_str}")
        print(f"Item information saved to {output_file_path}")

    else:
        print("Request to the Hypixel API was not successful.")

else:
    print("Failed to connect to the Hypixel API.")
```

This is the error:

```
Fetching Auction Data:  98%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▋  | 56/57 [00:09<00:00,  5.68page/s]
Auction Count: 6309
BIN Count: 48949
Total Count: 55258
Failed to retrieve data for item(s):
Item UUID: 66dbaa21641a42b7b17650797ef9e94a | Item Name: Heroic Glacial Scythe ✪✪✪✪✪➌
Item UUID: fae307212d1b4e7f952c43c15d50901f | Item Name: Jerry-chine Gun
Item UUID: c6c062dbeb614fcaaf3a6486d29e92b5 | Item Name: Bedrock
Item UUID: cf796df270d14749b88b101ff4c958c0 | Item Name: Giant Old Dragon Helmet ✪✪✪✪✪ ✦
Item UUID: 86d95bf300d14999bd18ebddec4e3442 | Item Name: Newton Nether Warts Hoe
Item UUID: d67793049bb744779c923a81d18e8f22 | Item Name: Newton Nether Warts Hoe
Item UUID: 806477620afa48a1a793c11463729f42 | Item Name: Newton Nether Warts Hoe
Item UUID: e5f2a690947a49c3b29d10fd60f23779 | Item Name: Newton Nether Warts Hoe
Item UUID: 4a7d7a58248e448d8532d3d5d74efe17 | Item Name: Newton Nether Warts Hoe
Item UUID: 67ee64bb4030458b868ba421de42167f | Item Name: Newton Nether Warts Hoe
Item UUID: 79ba87468f244ff4bcb52ff1c8bb12c5 | Item Name: Newton Nether Warts Hoe
Item UUID: 994d5336e61745129a3ac6c333800097 | Item Name: Newton Nether Warts Hoe
Item UUID: 6af7c96f375d47a6bbccbf94966fed44 | Item Name: Newton Nether Warts Hoe
Item UUID: 68449b29c3044e1f938b3f919be476ce | Item Name: Newton Nether Warts Hoe
Item UUID: 84a4bad5282248a288e610abcca439ab | Item Name: Newton Nether Warts Hoe
Item UUID: b024de707d3545b397ebb20cc4d2fecf | Item Name: ⚚ Ancient Shadow Assassin Helmet
Item UUID: 071352c1c0e34ddfbf632a6b9ede0f0e | Item Name: Overflux Power Orb ✦
Item UUID: 6649665457004e02a760322bdb0b419f | Item Name: Fervor Chestplate
Item UUID: 6e638fd90f1a45668486beb01ade2fd1 | Item Name: Withered Giant's Sword ✪✪✪✪✪
Item UUID: da6252f860eb4038868bcca71b373b3a | Item Name: [Lvl 1] Droplet Wisp
Item UUID: b1dbe28b177a4ddc890d0387dfce57fc | Item Name: [Lvl 1] Droplet Wisp
Item UUID: 32d1b22aba564088b2b922d4c090a3c2 | Item Name: Bedrock
Item UUID: acf3e05c97db44eda83144deece07bc2 | Item Name: Cobblestone Wall
Item UUID: 21cb8fe447ce4869bfba7f06b33581a2 | Item Name: Fabled Edible Mace
Item UUID: 2eef57ae53244d899c86424e821ed605 | Item Name: Fabled Livid Dagger ✪✪✪✪✪
Item UUID: 01b468330baa4e4da4d8b204e20d9880 | Item Name: Oxford Shoes
Item UUID: 830cdbe09ce54709a44b9dd524c82ad7 | Item Name: Frog Barn Skin
Item UUID: 55b0a2035b784f1994635db6eaee7973 | Item Name: Neon Tiger Skin
Item UUID: 758e65e54a9740fb8e191d8a28eafb61 | Item Name: Neon Tiger Skin
Item UUID: 42d99f494c3b4bfeb291fec582a05b8d | Item Name: Neon Tiger Skin
Item UUID: a12b59876e344174833c9c5bba7e0850 | Item Name: Crimson Leggings
Item UUID: 10cf2ab20c764de29ed1a42ab6574b96 | Item Name: Travel Scroll to Howling Cave
Item UUID: fa7c746237ca46d0b3ae2aed5420e135 | Item Name: [Lvl 100] Blue Whale
Item UUID: e75efbe5f3224a2384ad75f8f3cf5aa2 | Item Name: Pythagorean Potato Hoe
Item UUID: d6d06291028f4ee48ae845d25268a0ad | Item Name: Aurora Leggings
Item UUID: 53379d7561a344888a1bf49bd49513d3 | Item Name: Blood God Crest
Item UUID: 46b3571c03fd43ac8f96202246dea28d | Item Name: New Year Cake (Year 19)
Item UUID: fed72c1627aa4a98bacae0c009b1f287 | Item Name: [Lvl 100] Rock
Item UUID: cb054bca02e34fac93284ad4a2201af0 | Item Name: [Lvl 100] Rock
Item UUID: 2d9b16da644e4fbd8d4726e58de04d7c | Item Name: [Lvl 100] Rock
Item UUID: 3a2ea9aad40d4e818aa6203e1409dfc8 | Item Name: Aurora Boots
Item UUID: 3f01027a7e414bdb8e69206cc8598f1d | Item Name: Blessed Pumpkin Dicer 3.0
Item UUID: 0ba68faf5c5c421eb4e6d43c705eff20 | Item Name: Antique Remedies
Item UUID: 91145ad2fff34ce1bd767105d6b55e93 | Item Name: Antique Remedies
Item UUID: 11b4aaa0dcc1460995ac4c0aab9f949f | Item Name: Antique Remedies
Item UUID: 5b7dc2430b6943faaa68403ec5234799 | Item Name: Antique Remedies
Item UUID: b336de8a09454bcca275caa77ee59854 | Item Name: Antique Remedies
Item UUID: 6460f3c5889745789e4b607b3a9ff299 | Item Name: Antique Remedies
Item UUID: 3ba912b2bce54556a34144a5629f1319 | Item Name: Dead Bush
Item UUID: 2c83c13c0cb6418c93b0feaaa305bab4 | Item Name: Crimson Helmet
Item UUID: f3976bb478474430915ce7887280d48c | Item Name: Crimson Chestplate
Item UUID: 3d78b0f0222b4d0e9184333d804a653b | Item Name: Titanic Skeleton Soldier Helmet
Item UUID: 12902754417b476dbfce58c0649ceb0c | Item Name: Yellow Bandana
Item UUID: b28daf3deeb3484688e3d443da0b73ac | Item Name: New Year Cake (Year 270)
Item UUID: 0f87753b110646a7ab0aca38847ab2d4 | Item Name: Strengthened Magma Lord Gauntlet
Item UUID: 7e5af9b97f744265a2385ed0f17b64db | Item Name: Shaded Nether Artifact
Item UUID: 65a632182cac42f8b64137f077627eae | Item Name: Reaper Orb
Item UUID: 1303ae5a1a514eac9276399925ffaa7e | Item Name: Renowned Werewolf Chestplate ✪✪✪✪✪
Item UUID: 52d75c1b1fa14d24aca98d29b5db543c | Item Name: Necrotic Bat Person Leggings
Item UUID: c53b1bfe40bd43418a88eb1872183ff3 | Item Name: Necrotic Bat Person Boots
Item UUID: 99e01ad8ed30403b848859e6c3341289 | Item Name: Necrotic Bat Person Chestplate
Item UUID: 1321724b074d412ebc920a3757dfff9b | Item Name: Dwarven Tankard
Item UUID: 7e06c02f73bd4f2d99925b3df01abd60 | Item Name: Jasper Crystal
Item UUID: 207754ba2c5c44c1b624e56a29552d9b | Item Name: ⚚ Ancient Shadow Assassin Helmet ✪✪✪✪✪
Item UUID: eda5f9731bdf4fc087ac6363766765ea | Item Name: Aurora Chestplate
Item UUID: 7949b17c2edd4692bad607ee6e28eee0 | Item Name: Ember Fragment
Item UUID: 2517c91454ad443491a6bad08711337e | Item Name: Pythagorean Potato Hoe
Item UUID: 8ed2678eaae44521807864e994dc0c44 | Item Name: Lush Treecapitator
Item UUID: 834f5ff4599b4882abc71c6eac4b6c76 | Item Name: [Lvl 100] Ender Dragon ✦
Item UUID: 4c74a358df3b4d66a305c7db49bac14c | Item Name: [Lvl 100] Scatha ✦
Item UUID: 9d3db1a998b74f9bb24960a1a82cc382 | Item Name: Cropie Helmet
Item UUID: 596de462e30541559861c0dbca931b9c | Item Name: God Potion
Item UUID: 023023ead0854631bf6f5366f08ac0df | Item Name: God Potion
Item UUID: dbee54e976fb4fc983a0e919238b154c | Item Name: Molten Cloak
Item UUID: eb645fa30dc74bdf89365c03f045d4e6 | Item Name: [Lvl 1] Giraffe
Item UUID: 5c14b7f2807645fabe50cea22b239ba5 | Item Name: ◆ Couture Rune III
Item UUID: fb1622fd21c44f6199182697575eb07e | Item Name: Glistening Gauntlet of Contagion
Item UUID: 02688b6a104c474dac841072f869a882 | Item Name: Scythe Blade
Item UUID: 5b780ae4ef544f0b9aca2f23f6d7b00e | Item Name: Blessed Turing Sugar Cane Hoe
Item UUID: 11a5942d883140b29d5672affaead548 | Item Name: Aspiring Leap
Item UUID: cdee9b0042204119a7aef4467e7249eb | Item Name: Dungeon Orb
Item UUID: 489af6365eaf4b23b5567fc739d0fb87 | Item Name: Necromancer Sword
Item UUID: 524ce65e6a6446f59fcfe545e233fa8c | Item Name: New Year Cake (Year 21)
Item UUID: b02c90516f5d4d70a23b60a42c454a47 | Item Name: Dwarven Tankard
Item UUID: bcce9ec23edf4f6498db74d767a9e3ab | Item Name: Cocoa Plant
Item UUID: 9e4de7d6e20843769f2b5a440749907b | Item Name: Dwarven Tankard
Item UUID: 7c0c45e7242f42c8bfaecdd7ab85a357 | Item Name: Celestial Wither Goggles Skin
Item UUID: ddad5090c2c34f97ba26e80dfa63614a | Item Name: Dark Scatha Skin
Item UUID: 0e1dea6de18e47c496524dab63f6c8ef | Item Name: Burning Kuudra Core
Item UUID: 22a2207a3b054cb396b409289c961856 | Item Name: Burning Kuudra Core
Item UUID: a4a697a8da8143d09d97d09cf27a5c95 | Item Name: Burning Kuudra Core
Item UUID: 6236860b2d8c46c89def7572eabbf632 | Item Name: Burning Kuudra Core
Item UUID: 9cafc0672b5542d88d08ea6546515ac6 | Item Name: Dark Scatha Skin
Item UUID: c13158d80bf84236af187083223146eb | Item Name: Magma Necklace
Item UUID: 1a08602c9a694247bdf7ee46ab09e493 | Item Name: Scythe Blade
Item UUID: e736c156dda749bd84a65a7bc5d66ccb | Item Name: Scythe Blade
Item UUID: 9921a87b1493456788ff9a2459951f87 | Item Name: Tarantula Talisman
Item UUID: 67ba6a3d16b24d3186d568ba3ea502bf | Item Name: Scythe Blade
Item UUID: c2807eb46ff54f6cba2cec65f98d4831 | Item Name: Scythe Blade
Item UUID: e3859ed1d8c048729cd8e131ff35383f | Item Name: Gabagool the Fish
Item UUID: f2d538ee1d934044bf796659ca4b5b03 | Item Name: Blessed Pythagorean Potato Hoe
Item UUID: de59992f82aa4d178fa350b0d1bf35d2 | Item Name: Wise Sorrow Helmet
Item UUID: 2ddf753fcd4b417880f7138237b08cff | Item Name: Wither Cloak Sword
Item UUID: 2fde3322a897463785d67e28defa016a | Item Name: Wither Cloak Sword
Item UUID: 364905dfe43c43f0a731a5e775b12a81 | Item Name: Wither Cloak Sword
Item UUID: a3f418a9485a4e92a468c78b950c2a77 | Item Name: Glistening Gauntlet of Contagion
Item UUID: 43c292ad05d54384b4686f912e4d330f | Item Name: Hunter Ring
Item UUID: a542dd1bd8fa456ca13cbd5114b40308 | Item Name: Hunter Ring
Item UUID: 252f8d45b42f46e588807e07a546ae1b | Item Name: Blessed Gauss Carrot Hoe
Item UUID: f6dbfc02990d4bbeac8b74cd2901f109 | Item Name: Nether Artifact
Item UUID: ed35cb9adc0f409f87e539129098ce91 | Item Name: Jasper Crystal
Item UUID: 7a181b9c23a44c31a458f62f2008a973 | Item Name: Mithril-Plated Drill Engine
Item UUID: 360fe1343e614238a76768634d7db05a | Item Name: Mithril-Plated Drill Engine
Item UUID: f1d23bc20a8042fe9baaaf9c2bca6d78 | Item Name: Mithril-Plated Drill Engine
Item UUID: c792975a010c40d7a2b8c5662ac1917d | Item Name: Mithril-Plated Drill Engine
Item UUID: 768a41428069423691e0bda6a6e042cb | Item Name: Dark Scatha Skin
Item UUID: 09eda90a315a468690fc3eb8bb81533d | Item Name: Submerged Shark Scale Chestplate
Item UUID: cfdc39cc4acb4556aa4cff88d5856dbd | Item Name: [Lvl 1] Droplet Wisp
Item UUID: 7fb63fc4acdc430083ced1a5e8ad12e4 | Item Name: Gift the Fish
Item UUID: 173a41e09b004e8480de22205afbf7cd | Item Name: Ember Fragment
Item UUID: e262c5f3680b4d37996256a86ec20540 | Item Name: Ancient Frozen Blaze Chestplate ✪✪✪✪✪
Item UUID: 6fe6b712bcfc46388b333aadbc291bbd | Item Name: [Lvl 100] Sheep ✦
Item UUID: ad19a387c6a84f1bba18a3f8c6e71e9a | Item Name: Wise Great Spook Helmet
Item UUID: 40fd743c892247b7ac80e1371725bc84 | Item Name: New Year Cake (Year 1)
Item UUID: 99305c3a195d4906935efe0bd7ef3ff6 | Item Name: True Warden Skin
Item UUID: 11a24f8b2ea346fe833201038d059faf | Item Name: Spicy Voidwalker Katana
Item UUID: 0331b735145b4e53ac7bf6f434bacea7 | Item Name: Trapper Crest
Item UUID: 38e3e65631964f90a72387eae9990d6e | Item Name: Ancient Final Destination Helmet
Item UUID: 3d6fe6f598fe4e96a9bdfa62455482f8 | Item Name: True Warden Skin
Item UUID: e13e8394492047959c68855184e61bd4 | Item Name: Hyperion
Item UUID: 89c7dc0e3ca04e09b01524b7db8574a9 | Item Name: True Warden Skin
Item UUID: 5f53ff9a37794b1e9d642f6248c03642 | Item Name: Diamond the Fish
Item UUID: 5f725babfa3f4500b4c5a62318cbc138 | Item Name: null
Item UUID: a6fc50b556f044ac87ae4154f9d7c4a2 | Item Name: Nether Artifact
Item UUID: 547aeb8beb4f49649b578d5000569396 | Item Name: True Warden Skin
Item UUID: 775d41e7f1a7473b93d7a12ea5461a35 | Item Name: Fabled Ember Rod
Item UUID: 40851d0658d14f75b0f6f2eee3d2fecd | Item Name: Stick
Item UUID: 0766a367a37f40f086f0b3b5afe88f11 | Item Name: Aurora Helmet
Item UUID: 4c3bb8bd031e4a5ebceffe0872201b2f | Item Name: Builder's Ruler
Item UUID: 771d3f91f33c4b8f825f2b3452f8f7f5 | Item Name: Mathematical Hoe Blueprint
Item UUID: 387c9dac2d044933a0d888b023e80bc0 | Item Name: [Lvl 96] Bal
Item UUID: 93ec7d0237194a8c8ebbfd3ce81d4f2b | Item Name: Pure Super Heavy Chestplate
Item UUID: 55c53e50723e48e286b212b12c5a45ba | Item Name: Necrotic Rancher's Boots
Item UUID: caa790dbfaaf4e909d3530523b4a24bc | Item Name: Terror Leggings
Item UUID: cf4b7127e1964cb1b7b3e3faf8ec2ffb | Item Name: Aurora Chestplate
Item UUID: 6688dd734aac46f38dd2fc7010616ca7 | Item Name: Molten Belt
Item UUID: ee9f8c0523c041acb563a5f9a999408c | Item Name: Summoning Ring
Item UUID: 8c08e89f1411428988bba9cca7ba26fd | Item Name: Young Dragon Leggings
Item UUID: 5211214c1a0c42ca936fb55688da7af6 | Item Name: Bunny Minion Skin
Item UUID: a1c6647c424f4577b79b20e81d9baf17 | Item Name: Wand of Restoration
Item UUID: 3db4eb0c6c6e4acd8cb4847001d2aa51 | Item Name: Ice Cream Minion Skin
Item UUID: 86042b55b7694e348856cbe6ec2e42a5 | Item Name: Builder's Ruler
Item UUID: 5720c83e293b4032ad4c9cbeb7f0ab94 | Item Name: Fervor Helmet
Item UUID: f23d3ac59e484e0fa42d7490d7524f4e | Item Name: Red Snubfin Dolphin Skin
Item UUID: 27e3c0418aaf4867acc7197c8193f9a5 | Item Name: Purple Jerry Talisman
Item UUID: a3fb479232c9417a9c871e5aac4a0b4e | Item Name: [Lvl 1] Monkey
Item UUID: e23639c549a34587a33a574bdbf67880 | Item Name: Golden Monkey Skin
Item UUID: 55041a20a35b4747b45f5413f1308785 | Item Name: [Lvl 100] Pig
Item UUID: b918df2ae0de42ef903374216143aae1 | Item Name: God Potion
Item UUID: 57c2e3d12a8443bcbfc2cf56bfb3fa3e | Item Name: God Potion
Item UUID: bdcfa624131948299016a7e054f1d2c3 | Item Name: Summoning Ring
Item UUID: 58eeee07285d4ba9871c643edc5c4430 | Item Name: Blessed Pythagorean Potato Hoe
Item UUID: c66fdeddc6d74957b50413c49df0806e | Item Name: Cashmere Jacket
Item UUID: 3df5d47247764adfa559a1ee3e79f38c | Item Name: Travel Scroll to Howling Cave
Item UUID: 3a1ecc4c025246158e83c86eabd98f94 | Item Name: Travel Scroll to The Park
Item UUID: 48ee90248e504feba7fa6b4d55f89118 | Item Name: Travel Scroll to Dragon's Nest
Item UUID: 72dfc9f15a744977af2b717d613190a4 | Item Name: Travel Scroll to the Dwarven Forge
Item UUID: 059ad17bb1a942fa99b1aa6c509d60e0 | Item Name: ◆ Lavatears Rune III
Item UUID: 2b00295d302f4b11866b96c90f6ebf4a | Item Name: ◆ Lavatears Rune III
Item UUID: 49275cacc00b4e80b13fa52d189bc09e | Item Name: ◆ Lavatears Rune III
Item UUID: e0f5f6c792194591b57c56b914bf5f3d | Item Name: Kat Flower
Item UUID: ad3f0ab3405a45d0980d2e83cfc8500b | Item Name: God Potion
Item UUID: cde4194b4d81451389515d73e54fcee0 | Item Name: Antique Remedies
Item UUID: 6d318062c553476fb1de6c7f62a9a6e1 | Item Name: Dungeon Orb
Item UUID: 325c1651a0f949f4aacd99a6b785f0d1 | Item Name: Ancient Necron's Leggings ✪✪✪✪
Item UUID: f4ecaf5b7fd14e9e87a954a57a195f1f | Item Name: Fierce Strong Dragon Chestplate
Item UUID: 2bbd1796f62646d68e27e11a364e50d8 | Item Name: Pure Strong Dragon Chestplate
Item UUID: 157b3cb0cdbc44eda9844dc82fa640ec | Item Name: Necrotic Maxor's Leggings ✪✪✪✪✪➍
Item UUID: e9359fb2e29f43c68ddb24d6e544a335 | Item Name: Pink Donut Minion Skin
Item UUID: 564a2fb900e347a1b37e927838e023e7 | Item Name: Fire Fury Staff
Item UUID: bf1c009849c44c149484b5d2c2f25b23 | Item Name: New Year Cake
Item UUID: c709c4e494354a9ba410692ab16f3d3a | Item Name: Velvet Top Hat
Item UUID: 3b2a09807c15446aa3a9001b3557f329 | Item Name: Cashmere Jacket
Item UUID: 43201e30430244a294d85e07c5e0e168 | Item Name: Withered Flower of Truth ✪✪✪✪✪
Item UUID: 1719af3b37e3445a8aa6e92c790e5fee | Item Name: Molten Necklace
Item UUID: d0b1b81dd7794c6ea2d7f42e259eb491 | Item Name: null
Item UUID: c84ba3e2b4064eacb4a1174ab3b13bc4 | Item Name: Terror Leggings
Item UUID: c16acf1dc7a54560977ed3595db2f8ce | Item Name: Summoning Ring
Item UUID: cfa562821aba40a2b44f2ff0cba36547 | Item Name: Crimson Leggings
Item UUID: f460de2ac5ca4f5c98c56bb597bdb55b | Item Name: Gilded Midas' Sword ✪✪✪✪✪
Item UUID: 6109a11f347440c48966b75469b2150b | Item Name: Cashmere Jacket
Item UUID: 2318554e1e214ce79382c4330fdd1317 | Item Name: Giant Fairy's Fedora
Item UUID: 567c8368e7eb4ed58c08b793a6990d5e | Item Name: Giant Fairy's Polo
Item UUID: 352127093d6941e2924faf8584fd1789 | Item Name: Rooted Lotus Cloak
Item UUID: 6924d61ce29141438528d57a5036f00f | Item Name: Gauntlet of Contagion
Item UUID: 8ede8b48edf0471b8e3f25d36bd57311 | Item Name: Wither Leggings
Item UUID: b27b7663b3aa4a04abee2d8651a81a7c | Item Name: Pure Tarantula Chestplate
Item UUID: 59c179e8f08440ed837516f52ca13f45 | Item Name: null
Item UUID: 1b7e1ba4bf654da8b3b60f299da36452 | Item Name: Velvet Top Hat
Item UUID: 4af81cc28a7a45a399f4e82624758d50 | Item Name: Necron's Boots
Item UUID: 1806a40c223f4e7a81d25f82407deae5 | Item Name: God Potion
Item UUID: 5e56e19150b449a9b604c488e9685b08 | Item Name: Necromancer Lord Helmet
Item UUID: fcae3611c11f4803a908ac679c16760f | Item Name: Heroic Necromancer Sword ✪
Item UUID: cc61751ac9bd46568a49b25342720fe7 | Item Name: Gold Horse Armor
Item UUID: 99646f422f4641b8b215940f2a5d4b19 | Item Name: Gold Horse Armor
Item UUID: 785a0dabce324b7e941c7317cdb87f49 | Item Name: Gold Horse Armor
Item UUID: ce1d450a30ed46bdbbc7365494e40029 | Item Name: null
Item UUID: 1ca4e42baa854984a3579b5ab203788a | Item Name: Glistening Vanquished Blaze Belt
Item UUID: c374dd5f28644fbda9256c778b989673 | Item Name: Titanium Artifact
Item UUID: 187b7aec86f34a10a2576462204ff573 | Item Name: Odd Zombie Soldier Cutlass
Item UUID: 32c6298f4ffa43698dede990a410a052 | Item Name: Blessed Fungi Cutter
Item UUID: 5c2766c0f1304e1ab7e70a553d33ddfa | Item Name: Attribute Shard
Item UUID: 5d5867863ccb41689ed66d34aef509e4 | Item Name: Attribute Shard
Item UUID: 30933d67bf2644f98ab748914b258a92 | Item Name: Santa Minion Skin
Item UUID: 45072ce2fcce40be8f9869e43aeb3954 | Item Name: Santa Minion Skin
Item UUID: 972b98e5103945eda52cc845843588b4 | Item Name: Santa Minion Skin
Item UUID: 4bd65ea2ffa74b038dc491ab862b5d6f | Item Name: New Year Cake (Year 222)
Item UUID: bf3d78ee20824b0c9e08f369a232adff | Item Name: ⚚ Fierce Shadow Assassin Helmet ✪✪✪✪✪
Item UUID: 029d97e34195403c8c6f08d0596de559 | Item Name: Krampus Helmet
Item UUID: ce36364465b240cc941008c2aab4db18 | Item Name: Krampus Helmet
Item UUID: cd5150fe0155493295d7184e91f03eac | Item Name: Bingo Artifact
Item UUID: 8218b005d4c6422da879b92ece4bc32a | Item Name: Aurora Boots
Item UUID: 41e3ff8423ce475780b35c114924b23d | Item Name: Oxford Shoes
Item UUID: fe387b5ab2c34ecd9de8a64d055fd81c | Item Name: Personal Compactor 7000
Item UUID: 4c2ae3dc6e5e4c93bcdafba3395c7497 | Item Name: Necrotic Necromancer Lord Chestplate ✪✪✪✪
Item UUID: 6b66cdf2f3154644acc0b7f7186c9926 | Item Name: Great Spook Artifact
Item UUID: b22e3dc16cc9478f92b3d68a13016e41 | Item Name: New Year Cake (Year 24)
Item UUID: b3525c750d22462ebaf911f21e293c0f | Item Name: Festive Magma Lord Boots
Item UUID: ecc9390060aa49559dc125d6e6ad5bd4 | Item Name: Wither Boots ✪
Item UUID: 369644c2b1594e4ba86621f03224492c | Item Name: God Potion
Item UUID: d5d8a7c562e94cd0a028e46022a2afef | Item Name: Light Mineral Leggings
Item UUID: 7e5da78dc68f4bacb776a31d5a2796f9 | Item Name: Heated Titanium Drill DR-X655
Item UUID: 12eab97b0874417e826cda68530e5d6a | Item Name: Skeleton Skull
Item UUID: 52561f7c999c43aa80658756c48638df | Item Name: The Apprentice, Part 2
Item UUID: ca513d549f2a4e248e2b4c69381ce391 | Item Name: ◆ Endersnake Rune III
Item UUID: d865da03c98e426a8bf98a405db238ea | Item Name: Molten Bracelet
Item UUID: e037f777d3ad42d0a261c5af11e10e3a | Item Name: Light Young Dragon Boots
Item UUID: 16b157350ec947bfb1f4d5f8095c743b | Item Name: New Year Cake (Year 95)
Item UUID: f1d8916b1118485188063f333f4d4e02 | Item Name: Unreal Hurricane Bow
Item UUID: 317a5b69bfb842b98b50768f7ed802dd | Item Name: Heroic Aspect of the Dragons ✪✪✪✪✪
Item UUID: 50a308b6901743a0b50ea79ba383dce5 | Item Name: Fabled Flower of Truth ✪✪✪✪
Item UUID: 63db298932bf4b529b6a569b60e4fe4f | Item Name: Midas' Sword
Item UUID: b2915fad182b4cc1812d6d8ee735095e | Item Name: Red Crab Hat of Celebration - 2022 Edition
Item UUID: 894ff1f7d3714d8c8e64be75a82c0d7b | Item Name: Strong Tarantula Leggings
Item UUID: f08ac4c155874751a62e716c854161d1 | Item Name: Cashmere Jacket
Item UUID: c1c8138d15d44e7f9404ad658c7a3859 | Item Name: Newton Nether Warts Hoe
Item UUID: e6db5c97b90f4a4aae09b376fa121b4e | Item Name: Ancient Necron's Boots ✪✪✪✪✪
Item UUID: 2afe808edc2c4710a798ab6bcc31accd | Item Name: Aurora Helmet
Item UUID: 742c571010d44a8ea8774e96fbaaf067 | Item Name: Accessory Enrichment Swapper
Item UUID: cd7349c492494d7f951949ebdb3e11f8 | Item Name: Matriarch's Perfume
Item UUID: 2c9cffe3de8845b68aaa2adeb1cb610d | Item Name: Builder's Ruler
Item UUID: a277c5545daf4cb1ab725a521bef608a | Item Name: Rooted Lotus Cloak
Item UUID: c2ea25931408416087a7c47b4f248fcc | Item Name: [Lvl 1] Bal
Item UUID: a16794d7aad145b58a831eb2131c4389 | Item Name: Blessed Gauss Carrot Hoe
Item UUID: 195912c539cd4dc9b345f1a4933bfa06 | Item Name: Rooted Lotus Necklace
Item UUID: 0e5995960c3543e793171fed160387b9 | Item Name: Rooted Lotus Cloak
Item UUID: cb74dc58f726416ba32f464d9dd2d9fb | Item Name: Rooted Lotus Bracelet
Item UUID: 70391b9c1f5640e9b22879fda91373fe | Item Name: Artisanal Shortbow
```